# VBA: When referring to another sheet it's not being found

Tags: vba, excel, loops

New to the community, so please excuse any mistakes.

Using VBA I'm trying to loop through some sheets in excel (actions will be added later). 
However when SH=2 it hits a 40036 error on the second line which i can not explain.
Maybe someone else can? (BTW, the workbook has 5 sheets at the moment)

```
For Sh = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sh).Name <> "Overview" Then
        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sh).Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is this Excel or Google Spreadsheets? They're not the same thing, and they're not synonyms. Which one of the two are you actually using? Tags have specific meanings here, and those meanings are relevant. Do not just randomly add tags because they have familiar words or phrases in them - use **only** the tags that are actually relevant to your question.

Comment: As the post says, it's excel....

Comment: Then why do I see a  Google-spreadsheet tag on the question (still)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way to do the same process (won"t give you the error which I'm guessing is the result of an indexing error)

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> "Overview" Then
       MsgBox(Sh.Name)
    End If
Next Sh
```

Comment: Thx, indeed seems to solve the issue. Does this mean in general that indexing in sheets gives some weird errors and i should avoid it at all costs?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted in your question...  Something else maybe you didn't mention is causing the problem.